# How can I change the camera to include more of my scene?

Tags: rendering, objects, camera

As you see in the picture I am looking at the room modeled through the camera perspective:

[image: Camera view]

I want to change my camera settings to be able to render a picture of the whole room. How can I do that?

Comment: you can change the focal length of your camera to a lower value like 24mm.

Comment: Just for the record the correct term is not focus but **field of view**.

Comment: Just keep in mind, that a lot of the time, you don't want huge focal lengths in your renders. I can make a much less pleasing image, because there is less focus, and your trying to show off your entire scene at once which can b extremely distracting to look at, especially if it's big and has a lot of detail, instead, you should probably find a few elements in your interior, and try to make a few images, that focus on those objects. This should result in much more pleasing images. But the answer to your question is below.

Comment: Focal Length is the correct term, and is different from Focus distance. No one uses Field of View when talking about a lens in real life.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**This is the Default 35mm frame**

[image]

---

There are **two ways** you can bring more content into frame.

---

1. Lower the focal length of the camera, in this case from `35mm` to `25mm`

[image]

2. Back the camera up (I prefer fly mode over grabbing because I can see the result while doing so)

   - Go into fly mode, `shift + f`,
   - do not move the mouse while doing this (otherwise you will change what you are looking at)
   - back up, `s`

[image]

---

Note that cameras with a low focal length can look weird, look at this `10mm` example

[image]

Comment: For large fields of view, you could also use a [panoramic (fisheye / equirectangular) camera](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Cycles/Camera#Panoramic). In particular, you'll need a panoramic camera if you want the field of view to exceed (or even get close to) 180 degrees.

Answer (score 0):

Focal lengths are good, but what I find useful for many of my projects is opening the menu by pressing "n", go into camera view by pressing 0, and then enabling the "Lock camera to view" option.  This will allow you to change the camera angle just as easily as you normally can in the viewport.